# Render html code in a dataframe column using python streamlit

Tags: streamlit

Hello friends,
I have a pandas dataframe in which one of the column contains HTML codes. I am using streamlit app to display the dataframe in UI. How do I hide the HTML code and display it as a hyperlink preferrably `click here` and when clicked it should render the code and display as a HTML page?

Here is the pseudo code:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

data_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1,2,3,4],
        "apps": [
            "<!DOCTYPE html>\
                <html>\
                <body>\
                        \
                <h1>Heading 1</h1>\
                </body>\
                </html>",
                "<!DOCTYPE html>\
                <html>\
                <body>\
                        \
                <h1>Heading 2</h1>\
                </body>\
                </html>",
            "<!DOCTYPE html>\
                <html>\
                <body>\
                        \
                <h1>Heading 3</h1>\
                </body>\
                </html>",            
                "<!DOCTYPE html>\
                <html>\
                <body>\
                        \
                <h1>Heading 4</h1>\
                </body>\
                </html>",
        ],
    }
)

st.write(data_df)
```

This is how it is displayed now: [image]

Comment: Could be related to https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.column_config